# Comparing and selecting the row having highest value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select the `td` which has the highest value and mark it with a tick.

For instance I have

```
<td class="info">55</td>
<td class="info">66</td>
<td class="info">44</td>
```

Now when I try to take the value from the `tds` it just shows the first one

```
 $(document).ready(function(e)
 {
    var value = $(".info").text();
    alert(value);
 });
```

Can anyone tell me how to begin it with? how to get data and process it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `text` method always returns the text content of the first matching element, ignoring all the others.

To look at all of them, use `map`, returning for each element the text value, converted to number (with `+`). Then convert the resulting jQuery collection to a plain array with `get()`. Then it is easy to get the maximum value, its position, and target it with jQuery's `eq()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var values = $(".info").map(function () {
    return +$(this).text(); // convert to number
  }).get(); // convert to array
  // Get the maximum value
  var max = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
  // Get position of where the maximum value is
  var index = values.indexOf(max);
  // Apply marking
  $(".info").eq(index).addClass('tick');
});
```

```css
.tick { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="info">55</td>
    <td class="info">66</td>
    <td class="info">44</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you have multiple rows of which you need to highlight the greatest value, create a function that accepts a selector:

```js
function highlightGreatest(selector) {
  var values = $(selector).map(function () {
    return +$(this).text(); // convert to number
  }).get(); // convert to array
  // Get the maximum value
  var max = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
  // Get position of where the maximum value is
  var index = values.indexOf(max);
  // Apply marking
  $(selector).eq(index).addClass('tick');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    highlightGreatest('.info');
    highlightGreatest('.info2');
});
```

```css
.tick { background: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="info">55</td>
    <td class="info">66</td>
    <td class="info">44</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="info2">55</td>
    <td class="info2">66</td>
    <td class="info2">144</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Okay this cleared a lot of my problems! Thanks a million!

Comment: One more question, jquery is not my side but still I do it. My question is that what if there are three other rows that have different data lets say first three rows are of product_score and the other three rows are of sale_score. Now, should I write function for each of the three sets of rows or can one function evaluate and mark as highest. Like highest from product_score rows and highest from sale_score.

Comment: You can use one function if you have the selector right -- why not use a different class for the three first and the three last? Then you can write a function that takes that selector as argument, and does the hard work. Then you call that function twice: once with the first selector, and once with the second.

Comment: Yeah! Got that! I made the function and calling it by passing class as argument

Comment: Also added an example to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var max = 0,
  el, val;
$(".info").each(function() {
  val = parseInt($(this).text());
  if (val > max) {
    max = val;
    el = $(this);
  }
});

console.log(el);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="info">55</td>
      <td class="info">66</td>
      <td class="info">44</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Youll have to convert the text to integer values before comparing.

```
function compare() {
  var max=0,el,val;
  $(".info").each(function(){
     val = parseInt($(this).text());
     if(val>max) {
       max = val;
       el = $(this);
     }
  });
  return el;
}
```

Comment: Thank you now I understand the conceptuality

Comment: Happy to help. Updated the answer with a working code snippet.